# Return additional column if user is authorized - API

Tags: laravel-5.6

I have an Laravel-base API which handles both client and admin endpoints (there are two sites like `domain.com` and `admin.domain.com`).
My auth is based on cookie, which domain is `<.domain.com>`. As you can see, this cookie is acceptable for both domains.
I use Eloquent Api Resources for transformation data layer. Is my `when()` route check here safe and right?

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'created_at' => (string)$this->created_at,
        'status' => $this->when($request->route()->getName() === 'api.admin.users.index', $this->status)
    ];
}
```

Before I used `$this->when(Auth::check(), ...)`, but because my auth cookie is acceptable for client site too, unneeded data might be fetched.
My route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'api.admin.', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::resource('users', ...);
});
```

If user is not authorized, he wouldn't get data because of middleware. At the same time, authorized used (who has non-expired cookie) wouldn't get unneded data while being on client site.
Thank you!

Comment: I guess you have an additional login criteria available to identify admins - why not use this one here as well?

Comment: @Namoshek at the moment authorized user = admin. I don't event have role-based access control. So I can't check for user role or user auth status.

Comment: Why distinguish within the output at all then? Maybe come back later to this feature when you have implemented role-based authentication and there is a proper way for you to differentiate between users and roles. -- But to stay on topic, I added a short answer. Maybe it helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is fine. The route name is something internal and the user cannot tinker with it. You could improve it by using `\Route::is('api.admin.*')` though. It would then work for all of your admin API routes.